# Hi, I put the project on cpanel shared hosting, but the emails it wants to send iget Error message Mailer [SMTP] is not defined

Tags: php, html, laravel, smtp, cpanel

How can I solve this problem?

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp 
MAIL_HOST=mail.domainname.ir
MAIL_PORT=۵۸۷
MAIL_USERNAME=no-replay@domainname.ir
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=''
```

Comment: `MAIL_HOST=smtp.domainname.ir`  OR This problem is because smtp is not installed or configured on your server,Consult your hosting company.